# sklearn - ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'yes'

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset which has following categorical data [colname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRJAX.png). 
When performing one_hot_encoding using sklearn I get an error.

```
def ohe_encode(train, test, index):
    Onehot = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features='all', handle_unknown='error')
    x_train_1 = train
    x_test_1 = test
    colname = df.columns[index]
    Onehot.fit(train[colname].astype(str))
    x_trans = Onehot.transform(train[columnns].astype(str))
    new_features = Onehot.transform(test[colname].astype(str))
    return (x_transform, new_features)
```

error appeared on screen displaying,

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'yes'
```

not able to get cause of error.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please try to come up with more detailed titles (edited now).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [sklearns OneHotEncoder documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) (*emphasis mine*):

> Encode categorical **integer features** using a one-hot aka one-of-K scheme.
>
> The input to this transformer should be a **matrix of integers**, denoting
> the values taken on by categorical (discrete) features.

You, however, feed in the raw categorical values, eg. strings like «yes» and «no». Therefore you get the ValueError.

You need to [factorize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) your data first, which means you convert your strings into categorical numbers (integers). Then you can do the one hot encoding.